# how to set config inside of controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wrote as provider in application as below;

```
module.provider('CalculateTime', function() {


    this.$get = function() {
        var seconds = this.seconds;
        var minutes = this.minutes;
        var hours = this.hours;
        var day = this.day;

        return {

            toSeconds: function(){
                 return Math.round(seconds);
            },      

            toMinutes: function(){
                return Math.round(minutes);
            },

            toHours: function(){
                return Math.round(hours); 
            },      

            toDays: function(){
                return Math.round(day);
            },

            exactDate: function(){
                  return Math.floor(hours%24)+":"+ Math.floor(minutes%60)+":"+ Math.floor(seconds%60);              
            }    
        }
    };

    this.setTime = function(milis) {

        this.milis = milis;
        this.seconds = this.milis/1000;
        this.minutes = this.seconds/60;
        this.hours = this.minutes/60;
        this.day = this.hours/24;
    };
});
```

and I want to set config inside of controller ( after finished some preparation and set it up). So I tried as follows;

```
  module.controller('ResultController',function($scope,$data,CalculateTime){

     var date = $data.post.date;

     given.setDate(date.selectedYear,date.selectedMonth,date.selectedDay);

     var now =  new DateTime();
     var diff = now.compare(given);


    // config here         
    module.config(function(CalculateTimeProvider){
        CalculateTimeProvider.setTime(diff);
    });


    setTimeout(function() {
      $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.result =  CalculateTime.toDays() + " Days " +  CalculateTime.exactDate();
       });
     }, 100);
```

$scope.result is become null and nothing come out. I know that I'm wrong in usage and still don't know correct way to use whether service or provider or factory. Please tell me about correct ways of setting and retrieving.

Answer (score 0):

You can not configure a module after the bootstrapping phase. Configuration needs to happen BEFORE. You have to do this outside of your controller's scope.